# How exactly does ARQ (automatic repeat request) work?

Tags: data

As I understand it, **ARQ** is an error-checking method, which my textbook attempts to explain it as:

> ARQ uses an *acknowledgement* (a message sent by the receiver **indicating that the data has been recieved correctly**) and *timeout*. If an acknowledgement isn't sent back to the sender before timeout occurs, then the message is automatically resent.

The emboldened part is what stumps me: **how can the sender determine whether or not the data has been recieved correctly, and if it can do so, why even bother with ARQ since the sender already knows if the data has been transmitted correctly or not?**

---

Note: Please try explaining this in layman's terms as much as is possible.

Answer (score 2):

The receiver sends the sender a message (called acknowledgement), which says "i have received the data correctly". if the sender receives this message, the sender can be sure that the receiver has received the data.

The opposite is of course not true. If there is no acknowledgement, the data may have been received, but the sender has no way of knowing it, so it retransmits the data just in case.

Comment: the receiver determines that it was correctly received, usually because the packet has a checksum and it matches. then, if the receiver has received the data correctly, it sends the message to the sender, telling him that.

Comment: imagine you are talking to someone. and periodically, that someone makes a sound (saying something like yes, ok, or whatever), indicating that he understood you. This is somewhat how it works, you send someone a packet and they respond with "got your packet", so you are sure that they have got your packet.

Answer (score 0):

> why even bother with ARQ since the sender already knows if the data has been transmitted correctly or not?

Because data can be corrupted *in transit* (e.g. noisy phone lines or radio interference). Just because it was transmitted correctly doesn't mean it was *received* correctly.

Generally the receiver verifies some kind of checksum included in each frame, and if it doesn't match, then it knows that the data was corrupted and requests a repeat.

The difference between ARQ and FEC is that a checksum is weaker than an error-correcting code; it provides enough extra data to *detect* an error with high probability, but not enough to *correct* an error — the only way to get the correct frame is for the sender to re-send it (and hopefully it arrives intact the second time, otherwise it will have to be re-sent again). ARQ is only possible if the channel is two-way. If the error rate is fairly low (so that most frames don't have to be re-sent) then ARQ can be more efficient than FEC.